# Avada - editing the default 100%-width template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

To all the AVADA developers, how do I edit the 100% width page template? I would like to make my own version of the given file in my AVADA child theme.
In the AVADA (parent) theme I have found the 100-width.php file. I have copied this over to my currently active child theme. I have deleted everything apart head and footer. I have refreshed the page but I can not see any change to the template. Any advice? What am I doing wrong? Is this the correct file to edit? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This was a caching issue. The templating works as expected.